# VTD-XML: after initialization of the objects they still refer to null

Tags: java, vtd-xml

The problem is: after initializing VTDGen, VTDNav or AutoPilot in constructor, in the other method they refer to null and the appropriate exception is thrown.

```
public class Configuration {
public Configuration(String dir, String filename, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) throws IOException, IndexWriteException, IndexReadException {
    String XMLFilename = filename + ".xml";
    String indexFilename = filename + ".vxl";
    vtdGen = new VTDGen();

    vtdGen.parseFile("D:/Librarian/config/configuration.xml", true);
    vtdNav = vtdGen.getNav();
    autoPilot = new AutoPilot(vtdNav);
    boolean gen = vtdGen!=null;
    boolean nav =  vtdNav!=null;
    boolean pilot = autoPilot!= null;
    System.out.println("VTDGEN - " + gen + "\n" + "VTDNAV - " + nav + "\n" + "AUTOPILOT - " + pilot + "\n");
}

public Configuration(ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
    try {
        new Configuration(defaultDir, defaultFileName, resourceBundle);
    } catch (IOException | IndexWriteException | IndexReadException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}

public ArrayList<String> stringValue(String xPathExpression) {
    try {
        boolean pilot = autoPilot != null;
        System.out.println("AUTOPILOT - " + pilot + "\n" + "String.length = " + xPathExpression.length() + "\n" + "String = " + xPathExpression);
        autoPilot.selectXPath(xPathExpression);
        int i;
        while ((i = autoPilot.evalXPath())!=-1) {
            stringResult.add(vtdNav.toString(i));
        }
    } catch (XPathEvalException | NavException | XPathParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
    return stringResult;
}

public void writeIndex(File indexFile) {
    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(indexFile)){
        if (parsed) {
            vtdGen.writeIndex(fos);
        }
    } catch (IndexWriteException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}

public File createIndexFile(String dir, String filename){
    indexFile = new File(dir + filename + ".vxl");
    writeIndex(indexFile);
    return indexFile;
}

private final String defaultDir = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/config/";
private final String defaultFileName = "configuration";
private final String defaultXMLFile = defaultFileName + ".xml";
private final String defaultIndexFile = defaultFileName + ".vxl";

private boolean parsed;
private VTDGen vtdGen;
private VTDNav vtdNav;
private AutoPilot autoPilot;
private File indexFile;
private ArrayList<String> stringResult;
}
```

The result is:

```
VTDGEN - true
VTDNAV - true
AUTOPILOT - true
AUTOPILOT - false
String.length = 30
String = /configuration/lastMode/text()
```

The exception:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
...
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at core.config.Configuration.stringValue(Configuration.java:45)
at UI.PrimaryStageController.test(PrimaryStageController.java:77)
... 57 more
```

Why does autoPilot refer to null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you're calling this constructor:

```
public Configuration(ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
    try {
        new Configuration(defaultDir, defaultFileName, resourceBundle);
    } catch (IOException | IndexWriteException | IndexReadException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
}
```

That doesn't do what you think it does. It tries to create a new `Configuration` object, but doesn't actually do anything with it. Regardless of whether that constructor completes successfully or not, all the instance variables in *this* instance will have their default values.

You *could* chain to the other constructor instead using `this` - but then you'll have to declare that this constructor can throw the same checked exceptions:

```
public Configuration(ResourceBundle resourceBundle)
    throws IOException, IndexWriteException, IndexReadException {
    this(defaultDir, defaultFileName, resourceBundle);
}
```

You *can't* catch exceptions when you chain to another constructor.

If you really (really, really) want to suppress exceptions like this, you should probably turn this into a static method, and make sure you return a reference to the newly-constructed-with-actual-data object.

```
public static Configuration fromResourceBundle(ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
    try {
        return new Configuration(defaultDir, defaultFileName, resourceBundle);
    } catch (IOException | IndexWriteException | IndexReadException e) {
        // Swallowing exceptions? Really?
        e.printStackTrace();
        // At least the caller will get a null reference back instead of
        // a broken object...
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `this`:

```
public Configuration(ResourceBundle resourceBundle) throws Exception {
    this(Configuration(defaultDir, defaultFileName, resourceBundle));
}
```

In constructor:

```
public Configuration(ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
    try {
        new Configuration(defaultDir, defaultFileName, resourceBundle);
    } catch (IOException | IndexWriteException | IndexReadException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}
```

You created another instance of Configuration which gave you the output

```
VTDGEN - true
VTDNAV - true
AUTOPILOT - true
```

And you're calling method on another instance which initialized with default values for fields

**EDIT**

As Jon Skeet noted, you need to throw exception. Swallowing exception in constructor is a bad practice, since you successfully return from the constructor and object wasn't initialized correctly

Comment: Thank you, Jon! I've added a note on this